# Trouble using thrust complex(double) vector with sinus function

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have some problems using the `sin` function on a `Thrust` complex double vector on the device and on the host: it's seem like computation is done in float.

With `thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<double> >` and `thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<double> >`, I obtain:

```
sin( 1+0i ) == (0.8414709568023682,0)
```

with `std::complex<double>`:

```
sin( 1+0i ) == (0.8414709848078965,0)
```

and `std::complex<float>` :

```
sin( 1+0i ) == (0.8414709568023682,0)
```

What mistake did I do in my code? In the compilation process I used

```
nvcc test.cu -o test
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

template <typename Vector> 
void Print(Vector &V){
  for (int i=0;i<V.size();i++)
    std::cout <<  V[i] << "  ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
struct sin_functor : public thrust::unary_function< T , T >
{
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()( T x) const
  {
    return sin( x );
  }
};

template <typename Vector> 
void ThrustComputation(){
  typedef typename Vector::value_type Tvec;
  Vector A(2);
  A[0]=Tvec(1.,0.);A[1]=Tvec(1.,1.);

  std::cout << "A: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  ";Print<Vector>(A);

  Vector B(A.size());

  thrust::transform(A.begin(),A.end(),B.begin(), sin_functor<Tvec>());
  std::cout << "B =sin(A): " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  ";Print<Vector>(B);
}

template <typename T> 
void stdComputation(){
  std::complex<T> sA[2];
  sA[0]=std::complex<T>(1.,0.);
  sA[1]=std::complex<T>(1.,1.);

  std::cout << "sA: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  " << sA[0] << "  " << sA[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sin(sA): " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  " << sin(sA[0]) << "  " << sin(sA[1]) << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  std::cout << std::setprecision(16); 
  std::cout << "Thrust: Computation on GPU device (double)\n";
  ThrustComputation<thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<double> > >();
  std::cout << "Thrust: Computation on host (double)\n";
  ThrustComputation<thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<double> > >();
  std::cout << "std: Computation (double)\n";
  stdComputation<double>();
  std::cout << "std: Computation (float)\n";
  stdComputation<float>();
  return 0;
}
```

The output on my computer (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, cuda 7.5) is :

```
Thrust: Computation on GPU device (double)
A: 
  (1,0)  (1,1)  
B =sin(A): 
  (0.8414709568023682,0)  (1.298457622528076,0.6349639296531677)  
Thrust: Computation on host (double)
A: 
  (1,0)  (1,1)  
B =sin(A): 
  (0.8414709568023682,0)  (1.298457622528076,0.6349639296531677)  
std: Computation (double)
sA: 
  (1,0)  (1,1)
sin(sA): 
  (0.8414709848078965,0)  (1.298457581415977,0.6349639147847361)
std: Computation (float)
sA: 
  (1,0)  (1,1)
sin(sA): 
  (0.8414709568023682,0)  (1.298457503318787,0.6349638700485229)
```

Comment: what is your actual question? something like "why do `std::complex` and `thrust::complex` produce not exactly the same output?

Comment: For me, with  a thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<double> >  the computation of sin(1+0i) is false : the error with exact solution is 1e-8!

Comment: you can raise a bug report here: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be a genuine bug in the thrust library. A quick scan of the code on github led me to [this](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/2ef13096187b40a35a71451d09e49b14074b0859/thrust/detail/complex/csinh.h#L61), which might be the culprit. It seems that thrust's double precision `csinh` function, upon which complex `sin` relies, has an accidental intermediate cast to float, which is probably causing the loss of precision you have observed. As suggested in comments, you should report this as a bug.